# Frustrating dealing with Window Message(WM_XX)

Tags: windows, winapi, window, message

I'm trying to make myself a GUI library using plain WinAPI. But I found that dealing with Window Message really frustrating.

For example, I can see that when I move my mouse over my window, WM_NCHITTEST will send to me before WM_MOUSEMOVE.
But if I press down the left button, move around, then release the left button. Then I only receive WM_MOUSEMOVE afterward. Possibly it was because I call SetFocus(HWND), SetCapture(HWND) when receive WM_LBUTTONDOWN and ReleaseCapture(HWND) when receive WM_LBUTTONUP

These different behaviors seem like a mist to me. I wonder is there any documentation / article explaining the details about these Window Message. At least, tell me what I should pay attention to. (Charles's "Programming Windows" doesn't work for me, because it only introduce the basis about those messages, but not telling me traps like I mention about the WM_NCHITTEST / WM_MOUSEMOVE)

Comment: Sorry, make a mistake. I forget to call ReleaseCapture().Lol. Don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saying `SetCapture(HWND)` you asking system to redirect all mouse messages to your window until you call `ReleaseCapture(HWND)`. When mouse input is captured (so all messages redirected there) by some window there is no need to send `WM_NCHITTEST`.

If needed you can send WM_NCHITTEST to windows under the mouse by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618(VS.85).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/18/10131176.aspx

WM_NCHITTEST is for hit-testing. It only gets sent when needed. MSDN has documentation on each message. There is also a section on mouse input http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645533(v=VS.85).aspx